# SSRS Data Tablix Data Not Refreshing 'Go To Report' or 'Go To URL' Action

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

It's an SSRS 2012 installation in Native mode.  To be specific, this works perfectly as expected when run in BIDS / Visual Studio, but not when deployed on the reporting server.

I have a simple tablix with a few columns of data and a column with an 'X' indicator for a user to trigger a flip to a boolean in the row.  In essence, if they click this 'X' for a given row the report should refresh and the row should disappear from the tablix.

How I set it up is that clicking on the 'X' re-directs them to the same report (also tried it using a parameterized URL call to the same report, same issue), passing in the parameter of the ID of the row they want to delete.  This triggers a stored procedure call that updates the table.  However when the report refreshes, the row still appears. The parameterized call includes the &rs:ClearSession=true parameter as well.

The entire Go To URL call looks like this (with expression):
="http://Server/ReportServer?/Folder/Report+Name&ID=" & Fields!ID.Value & "&rs:Command=Render&rs:ClearSession=true"

I ensured that the stored procedure is getting called as expected and that the update is being made to the DB and all of that checks out.  When deployed, if I manually refresh the report after the initial redirect refresh or if I click the 'X' indicator a second time and the call is made again, it'll disappear as expected.

I tried moving the stored procedure call into the dataset directly to see if that made a difference, but no dice.

I would assume it's an ordering issue (the report is refreshing visually before the stored procedure call is actually completed) but I don't get why it works fine in VS but not when it's deployed out on the server.  IE and Chrome both seem to function identically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds cache-related, as you suspect. Try adding a dummy parameter to your report and pass it a unique value each time (like a GUID or timestamp) that you generate each time you render the report.

Comment: Went ahead an added a parameter "DateValue" and assigned it a query that simply calls "GetDate()" and it's passed each time when calling the stored procedure.  Even though the datetime value is changing every time, it still is exhibiting the same issue.

Comment: are you passing it from the report itself? Not enough if it's just server-side, needs to be a report parameter

Comment: I have a param on the report "DateValue", set to type Date/Time, allow null, hidden, no defaults (had one before).  When the 'X' is clicked on a row, it redirects populates the parameter like this: ="http://Server/ReportServer?/Folder/Report+Name&ID=" & Fields!ID.Value & "&rs:Command=Render&rs:ClearSession=true & "&DateValue=" & Now

Comment: Interestingly enough, imported the report on a SQL 2016 box and deployed out that report server and it works just fine there, not sure what the configuration difference might be.